# Connected user recovery

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I have a controller like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            "ref_ticket"=>['required','min:3'],
        ]);

        $verification=Affaire::where('reference', '=', $request->ref_ticket);
        //dd($verification->count());
        if($verification->count() >0){
            // exite
            return back()->with("error","Ce ticket ". $request->ref_ticket ." existe déjà veuillez le changer.");
        }else{
            // existe pas
        $tickets = new Ticket();
        $tickets->ref = $request->ref_ticket;
        $tickets->type_demande = $request->demande;
        $tickets->categorisation = $request->categorie;
        $tickets->severite = $request->severite_ticket;
        $tickets->sujet = $request->sujet_ticket;
        $tickets->fichier_joint = $request->fichier_joint_ticket;
        $tickets->message = $request->message_ticket;
        $tickets->progression = $request->progression_ticket;
        $tickets->date_cloture = $request->date_cloture_ticket;
        $tickets->etat = 'Assigné';
        $tickets->affaire_id = $request->affaire_ticket;
        $tickets->tier_id = $request->tier_ticket;
        $tickets->user_id = $request->user_ticket;


        $tickets->user_id = Auth::id();
        $tickets->save();
        return back()->with("success","Ticket ". $request->ref_ticket ." enrégistré avec succès.");
        }
        
    }
```

My Ticket table :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('ref')->nullable();
        $table->string('type_demande')->nullable();
        $table->string('categorisation')->nullable();
        $table->string('severite')->nullable();
        $table->string('sujet')->nullable();
        $table->string('fichier_joint')->nullable();
        $table->string('message')->nullable();
        $table->string('progression')->nullable();
        $table->string('date_cloture')->nullable();
        $table->string('etat')->nullable();
        $table->string('affaire_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('tier_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
```

I have a model: User

```
public function tickets(){
        return $this->hasMany(Ticket::class);
    }
```

I have another model: Ticket

```
public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,"user_id");
    }

    public function createdBy()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function tier()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Tier::class, 'tier_id');
    }

    public function assignedTo()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
```

and my blade view

```
@foreach ($tickets as $ticket)
<tr>
<th scope="row"><a href="/TICKETS/detail-ticket.html" class="link">{{ $ticket->ref}}</a></th>
<td>{{$ticket->createdBy->name}}</td>
<td>{{ $ticket->sujet}}</td>
<td>{{ $ticket->type_demande}}</td>
<td>{{ $ticket->severite}}</td>
<td>{{$ticket->tier->nom_prenoms}}</td>
<td>{{ $ticket->created_at}}</td>
<td>{{$ticket->assignedTo->name}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

I need to retrieve the user who submitted the ticket creation form via this `{{$ticket->createdBy->name}}` as well as the person to whom the ticket was assigned as a result `{{$ticket->assignedTo->name}}`. but it shows me the same user on both sides.

Any ideas ?

Comment: you are telling it to use the `user_id` field for 3 relationships, they will all return this same user because they are referencing the same exact field ... you have no field on the table for `created_by` or `assigned_to`

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same `user_id` in 3 different relationships( `user()` ,  `createdBy()` and `assignedTo()`). It should be separated so you know what you're doing with each field.

> Ex: Create a new field for `assigned user`. And normal `user_id` you can see who created the ticket.

In migration, create a new one.

```
Schema::table('tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('assigned_user_id')->nullable()->after('user_id');
    $table->foreign('assigned_user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

And in `Ticket` Model (if not, create a new one)

```
public function assignedTo()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'assigned_user_id');
}
```

In your update/store, don't forget to add the key if the value is present.

```
$tickets->assigned_user_id = $request->assigned_user_id;
```

> For this, you have to add a new input to add the assignee.

In your Blade view, you can now use `{{$ticket->createdBy->name}}` to get the name of the user who created the ticket and `{{$ticket->assignedTo->name}}` to get the name of the user to whom the ticket is assigned.